# Is blurring a watermark on a video clip a violation of copyright law, or is it legal?

Tags: copyright

We own a list channel on YouTube, we make videos such as “7 Biggest Houses in the World” everything is under fair use (we have a voiceover over the clips and we use minimal footage as possible) and sometimes there are watermarks on video clips, are we allowed to blur the watermarks on the clip? I know for a fact that cropping a watermark is a direct violation of copyright law, as stated on “Section 1202 of the U.S. Copyright Act” but what about blurring a watermark? One of my competitors that has 3 million subs on YouTube and he always blurs watermarks on video clips, really confused on if blurring a watermark is a direct violation of copyright law or if it’s ok to do and legal? If you search on YouTube "the finest 15 biggest trucks in the world" and if you go to 2:27 - 2:29 of the video, they’re blurring the watermark on the video clip and they do this for every video, so is this legal? Because news channels do that as well where they blur watermarks on video clips.

Comment: Do you have permission to use the clips in your videos? Did that permission come with a license allowing you to alter it? Are you obtaining video clips from a source that includes a license?

Comment: Have you read the section you cite?  It pretty consistently uses the phrase "remove or alter", so if you think that removing the watermark would be illegal, then altering it by blurring should be illegal too.

Comment: Nothing is definitely fair use until it's been judged so in court. Just because you *believe* your use of the copyrighted works falls under the provisions of the fair use clause doesn't mean you're right. If you have a lawyer who assures you that it's fair use, that's another thing, but even a lawyer isn't always right (and I expect no lawyer is going to assure or guarantee anything, merely advise based on experience and prior case law). If you or other content creators have not received any notices about infringement, that's not evidence of non-infringement. Just no one has noticed or cares.

Comment: If anything, it could be expected that the removal of the watermark without permission to be claimed by an adversary as evidence that you knew that your use of the video was not legal and that you were attempting to make more difficult for the owner to exercise his rights.

Comment: Are you sure it's under fair use? Many people think their use falls under fair use when it doesn't. AFAIK, "having a voiceover" is not a criterion for fair use...

Comment: Is the logo of a TV show a copyright indicator?

Comment: Not all watermarks are added by the copyright holder.  Many programs include watermarks throughout their entire duration, even in portions that make fair use of outside materials.  Networks may blur such watermarks to avoid helping the creators of such programs receive free advertising benefits from material they don't own.  With regard to the cited program, I don't think it sounds like fair use, since fair use protections mainly apply in situations where it would be impossible to replace the borrowed work with an original one.  If, for example, one is discussing the way that a particular...

Comment: ...artist does something, using anything other than the artist's actual work as an example wouldn't allow the reader/viewer to know whether the description would fairly apply to the artist's work, or merely to similar works by other artists.  If one wanted to do a show about the art of photographing houses, using other people's works as examples would be fair use, and if one were only using formulaic photographs of houses that would be essentially indistinguishable from other such photos, there might not be enough originality to merit protection.  But I doubt either situation applies here.

Comment: so are we allowed to blur watermarks on video clips, that isn't a violation of copyright law then, right? Because if you go to 2:27 - 2:29 of the video (look at the top left and bottom right, the watermark is blurred): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MigGVipftHI&t=150s - look through the entirety of the video, they're blurring watermarks on the video clips throughout almost all the clips (their editors do it, the clips dont come like that). Don't you guys think they know what they're doing considering they have a huge subscriber base of a channel

Comment: no, adam, that's not how it works. The news media can usually claim fair use because *news reporting is explicitly fair use* - but that applies only to **news**.

Answer (score 22):

[17 USC 1202(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/1202) states:

> *Removal or **Alteration** of Copyright Management Information*.—No person
> shall, without the authority of the copyright owner or the law— (1)
> intentionally remove or **alter** any copyright management information,
> (2) distribute or import for distribution copyright management
> information knowing that the copyright management information has been
> removed or **altered** without authority of the copyright owner or the
> law, or (3) distribute, import for distribution, or publicly perform
> works, copies of works, or phonorecords, knowing that copyright
> management information has been removed or **altered** without authority
> of the copyright owner or the law, knowing, or, with respect to civil
> remedies under section 1203, having reasonable grounds to know, that
> it will induce, enable, facilitate, or conceal an infringement of any
> right under this title.

In the suggested sample, it is impossible to judge whether the blurred SE corner is  “copyright management information”, defined in para (c), because it has been, well, blurred. For example, if the blurred portion says "Call now, operators waiting" or "Don't do this at home!", that is not copyright management information. Assuming that this is the manufacturer's name (the video being a work for hire so Terex holds the copyright), then blurring that label without permission would be a violation of this section of copyright law.

Comment: It says nothing here about altering, "Section 1202 of the U.S. Copyright Act makes it illegal for someone to remove the watermark from your photo so that it can disguise the infringement when used. The fines start at $2500 and go to $25,000 in addition to attorneys' fees and any damages for the infringement." - but overall blurring a watermark on a video clip is a violation of the copyright law, them why does my 5 million subscriber competitor doing that then, he blurs all the watermarks on every clip but he does give credit on the bottom left, but still

Comment: "Removing the watermark" includes "disguising the infringement". You don't have to physically remove it, making it unreadable is enough to constitute removal of the mark.

Comment: The part which I underlined from the US Code says "alter", so I don't know how you conclude that it says nothing about altering.

Comment: @Adam reread the answer - I put the formerly italicised words to bold. **ALTER**

Comment: then why does my competitor blur watermarks, do they not know about this? I mean they must know what they're doing since they have a big subscriber base with 5 million subscribers and im pretty sure that they must know what they're doing since they probably have gotten copyright lawyers for sure

Comment: @AdamL They might have paid for the right to do so. We can only speculate, since we don't know about private agreements they have with the copyright owners.

Comment: @Adam people, even big businesses, do all sorts of copyright infringing things all the time.

Comment: so are we allowed to blur watermarks on video clips, that isn't a violation of copyright law then, right? Because if you go to 2:27 - 2:29 of the video (look at the top left and bottom right, the watermark is blurred): youtube.com/watch?v=MigGVipftHI&t=150s - look through the entirety of the video, they're blurring watermarks on the video clips throughout almost all the clips (their editors do it, the clips dont come like that). Don't you guys think they know what they're doing considering they have a huge subscriber base of a channel

Comment: @adam, copyright law doesn't address "watermarks", it addresses Copyright Management Information. The blurred stuff could be anything: it could be done with permission. If you can locate an original video, we could at least limit this to "violation, or altered with permission".

Comment: Here's an [original frame](https://youtu.be/AAR992e0UuU?t=22) vs [altered fame](https://youtu.be/MigGVipftHI?t=179) for comparison.

Comment: It does look like the blurred stuff counts as Copyright Management Information: so, with permission, or a violation.

Comment: @Adam You don't decide "oh this is OK" by mimicking others who may have different private agreements with the copyright holder. Contact the copyright holder directly to ask, unless they already state a permissive license in their content.

Comment: @Trish you said, "then blurring that label without permission would be a violation of this section of copyright law." would that be the same as their watermark? What they blurred was their watermark. Keep in mind, this channel has 5 million subscribers and they do not contact any copyright holder, we know them. Here's an original frame (https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=22&v=AAR992e0UuU&feature=youtu.be) vs altered fame (https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=179&v=MigGVipftHI&feature=youtu.be) for comparison. They blurred the watermark, they have to know they're doing and it has to be part of fair use

Comment: any thoughts guys?

Comment: @Adam It comes down to what is being blurred. See [17 USC 1202(c)(1)-(8)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/1202). If you blur the title, author, copyright holder, performer, writer, director, terms and conditions for use, or identification information that links to any of those things, you need permission or you are violating the law. If someone watermarked a work with no particular authority to do so just because they distributed it and wanted credit for nothing, you can remove their watermark.

Comment: I was wondering, under section 1202 of the copyright act, it states that you can't alter any copyright management information, would this be considered copyright management information? Are we allowed to blur this, is this considered copyright management information: https://gyazo.com/023fca5bb3b050a752281a796e15bada @DavidSchwartz

Comment: @Adam The descriptive text at the bottom of that image does not contain anything that would be considered copyright management information as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for answering my question, what about this article? Go to the section that's labeled 1-8 that says "Section 1202(c) defines the term “copyright management information” to include any of the following information conveyed “in connection with” copies, displays, phonorecords, or performances of a work:" would the text in the screenshot that I provided fall under those categories you think? https://www.finnegan.com/en/insights/articles/define-your-terms-what-do-the-phrases-copyright-management.html#:~:text=Section%201202(c)%20defines%20the,on%20a%20notice%20of%20copyright.

Comment: @Adam I don't think so.